# Federated Engine PHPmyAdmin, MYSQL5, Magento, CPANEL

Tags: mysql, sql, cpanel, federated-storage-engine

I am trying to access some tables on an old magento database on a remote server. I am trying to recreate tables with a federated engine, inserting them on the local server with sql like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fed_customer_address_entity` (   `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity Id',   `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type Id',   `attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set Id',   `increment_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Increment Id',   `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Parent Id',   `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created At',   `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Updated At',   `is_active` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Is Active',   PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),   KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_PARENT_ID` (`parent_id`) ) ENGINE=FEDERATED connection='mysql://user:pass@test.ourwebsite.com/animaln2_MagentoTest/customer_address_entity';
```

But they are defaulting to MyIsam tables (I can see this when I export the table). Nor will it let me change the engine type to federated under "operations" tab. I am running MYSQL version 5.1.68-cll. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First off you need VPS or dedicated server of some sort to be able to activate the federated engine. Once I realized that there was a better way for me to do this, I strayed away from using federated. I actually only needed to access old data that was on a different server. So instead I downloaded the tables I needed access too and added it into a new database on the local server. Then I just made two links to the different databases and parsed the result adding them together. Sometimes you just wish you KISS in the first place :)